# Laravel request always return without referer

Tags: php, laravel, http, nginx

**laravel 7.19.1
php 7.4
nginx 1.17.10(ubuntu)**

> i tried to get HTTP_REFERER from request() or from $_SERVER always
> return without referer

dump request()->headers :

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\HeaderBag {#49 ▼

#headers: array:12 [▼
   "cookie" => array:1 [▶]
   "accept-language" => array:1 [▶]
   "accept-encoding" => array:1 [▶]
   "accept" => array:1 [▶]
   "user-agent" => array:1 [▶]
   "upgrade-insecure-requests" => array:1 [▶]
   "dnt" => array:1 [▶]
   "cache-control" => array:1 [▶]
   "connection" => array:1 [▶]
   "host" => array:1 [▶]
   "content-length" => array:1 [▶]
   "content-type" => array:1 [▶]
 ]
 #cacheControl: array:1 [▶]
}
```

dump $_SERVER:

```
"USER" => "www-data"
  "HOME" => "/var/www"
  "HTTP_COOKIE" => "XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IjBSMHk0ak8zUHNCVGIrRHpncXQxMlE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiWXQxUWRFWjFqQ0QyY05OVHhUOWVMcVFIdmdtNUNSK0liZFdRVVZXOTE1aUhhbGkvMDQxU1d6cjR0S3RzQ1hzbyIsIm1hY ▶"
  "HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE" => "en-US,en;q=0.9,ar;q=0.8"
  "HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" => "gzip, deflate"
  "HTTP_ACCEPT" => "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9"
  "HTTP_USER_AGENT" => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36"
  "HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS" => "1"
  "HTTP_DNT" => "1"
  "HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL" => "max-age=0"
  "HTTP_CONNECTION" => "keep-alive"
  "HTTP_HOST" => "example.com"
```

Comment: This depends on the browser, nothing PHP or Laravel can do about this.

Comment: @Jerodev i need to check the referrer url ,any suggestions?

Comment: Don't. This is something that can be very easily be tampered with. It should only be used for analytics purposes.

Comment: @Jerodev im working on shortlink script i need to be sure user redirect from the right url to add the profit to his balance